# Is Scala's inability to mix version in library fixed?

Tags: scala

I have learned that Scala is suffering from a limitation, that all Scala bytecodes needs to be generated from same compiler version.  e.g. I cannot have a library built for 2.9 to work with my application which is built by 2.9.1

http://lift.la/blog/scalas-version-fragility-make-the-enterprise

I tried to search from the web for more discussion on this issue but cannot find much updates.  Is this issue, as in Scala 2.11.6, fixed in any extend?

Comment: You can use any 2.11.x versions to compile and run with libraries compiled against each other. (There were some serialization problems in 2.11.0 which might cause problems and as I remember 2.11.4 were never released properly, so I would not use them for any purposes.) You can use libs compiled against 2.10.x with Scala 2.10.y, when `y>=x` (so those are backward compatible). 2.11.x is both backward and forward compatible within 2.11.x versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala, the 'middle' number in the version string is the **major version**, so in 2.10.x and 2.11.x, the major version is **10** and **11** respectively.

Major versions are *binary compatible.* Therefore, if you have a library compiled against Scala 2.11.0, you can safely use it in a project that uses 2.11.6 without recompilation, and vice versa. If your library was compiled for Scala 2.10.5, you would have to compile it newly to use in a Scala 2.11.x project.

If your code doesn't call into deprecated API, it should be *source compatible* with the subsequent major version.

---

Most libraries are published for at least two major versions at the same time, so there is quite a bit of elasticity. Take an example, Scalaz, it has its latest artifacts cross-built for [Scala 2.9.3](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22scalaz_2.9.3%22), [Scala 2.10.x](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22scalaz_2.10%22), and [Scala 2.11.x](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22scalaz_2.11%22).

Comment: I believe it is valid from 2.10? Coz iirc binary compatibility broke even for minor version when it is 2.8 or 2.9

Comment: Yes, Scala 2.8 and 2.9 are very old. The standard was established with 2.10 which is available since 2012. If you still use 2.9.x, you must use the correct minor version, i.e. 2.9.3.